# Update multiple columns of table using jpa

Tags: jpa

I have a customer table with 40 columns. There is a screen where i can update atleast 20 columns. Please tell me which is the better to call the jpa update. I m new to jpa. I cant call find by id and then one by one set all these 20 update column values. What if i pass the object with updated 20 values.. I m
Worrried it might override other 20 columns.

Comment: *I cant call find by id and then one by one set all these 20 update column values*: why?

Comment: I have more than on screens and i dont want to manually perform set all the values..i want to pass the object with updated values instead

Comment: Detach the object, pass it to the layer with the "screen" and update the 20 fields that are changed, then merge the updated object?

Comment: @abc Sounds like you are to worried to just give it a try? ;-)